# Verilator does not seem to recognize casez statement, any idea of how to solve this?

Tags: system-verilog, riscv, register-transfer-level, micro-architecture, verilator

I'm trying to code a riscv decoder in system verilog, here's the code :

```
case(opcode)
    7'b0110011: assign r_type          = 1'b1;
    7'b0010011: assign i_type          = 1'b1;
    7'b0000011: assign i_type          = 1'b1;
    7'b0100011: assign s_type          = 1'b1;
    7'b1100011: assign b_type          = 1'b0;
    7'b0110111: assign u_type          = 1'b1;
    7'b1101111: assign j_type          = 1'b1;
endcase

casez({opcode, funct3, funct7})
    // r-type
    {r_type, 3'b000, 7'b0000000} : assign add   = 1'b1;
    {r_type, 3'b000, 7'b0100000} : assign sub   = 1'b1;
    {r_type, 3'b001, 7'b0000000} : assign sll   = 1'b1;
    {r_type, 3'b010, 7'b0000000} : assign slt   = 1'b1;
    {r_type, 3'b011, 7'b0000000} : assign sltu  = 1'b1;
    {r_type, 3'b100, 7'b0000000} : assign xorr  = 1'b1;
    {r_type, 3'b101, 7'b0000000} : assign srl   = 1'b1;
    {r_type, 3'b101, 7'b0100000} : assign sra   = 1'b1;
    {r_type, 3'b110, 7'b0000000} : assign orr   = 1'b1;
    {r_type, 3'b111, 7'b0000000} : assign andd  = 1'b1;
    // i-type
    {i_type, 3'b000, 7'b???????} : assign addi  = 1'b1;
    {i_type, 3'b010, 7'b???????} : assign slti  = 1'b1;
    {i_type, 3'b011, 7'b???????} : assign sltiu = 1'b1;
    {i_type, 3'b100, 7'b???????} : assign xori  = 1'b1;
    {i_type, 3'b110, 7'b???????} : assign ori   = 1'b1;
    {i_type, 3'b111, 7'b???????} : assign andi  = 1'b1;
    {i_type, 3'b001, 7'b???????} : assign slli  = 1'b1;
    {i_type, 3'b101, 7'b???????} : assign srli  = 1'b1;
    {i_type, 3'b101, 7'b???????} : assign srai  = 1'b1;
endcase
```

It seems verilator doesn't recognize that ?? marks

I tried to ue casex and casez and i search through the verilator documentation but i didn't found any information about this

Comment: The `assign` keywords might be to blame and should be removed if this is part of an `always` block

Comment: you need to provide more code. If these are generate *case* statements, then it is correct because there is no 'casez' in generates, just 'case'.

Comment: I mean it's outputing an error saying casez isn't recognize. And it's not in an always block

Comment: I cant post the whole code but basically is all combinatory without any always statement

Answer (score 1):

A case statement outside of the always block is part of the generate construct. Per the LRM only `case` and `if` are supported for generate construct ([IEEE1800-2017](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html) § A.4.2 *Generated instantiation*). `casez` is not officially supported as a generate construct. Even then, the arguments and case item index must be constant expressions. You are using `opcode`, `funct3`, and `funct7` which are likely dynamic.

**Simple solution**: Use an always block. Drop the assign statments in the always block. And remember to initialize/set-default-value all variables assigned in the always block (or latches will be inferred). Reminder your variables should be defined as `logic` type for SystemVerilog (`reg` if Verilog).

```
always_comb begin // always_comb for SystemVerilog. Verilog use always @*
  // set default value
  r_type = 1'b0;
  i_type = 1'b0;
  s_type = 1'b0;
  b_type = 1'b0;
  u_type = 1'b0;
  j_type = 1'b0;
  add    = 1'b0;
  sub    = 1'b0;
  sll    = 1'b0;
  slt    = 1'b0;
  sltu   = 1'b0;
  xorr   = 1'b0;
  srl    = 1'b0;
  sra    = 1'b0;
  orr    = 1'b0;
  andd   = 1'b0;
  addi   = 1'b0;
  subi   = 1'b0;
  slli   = 1'b0;
  slti   = 1'b0;
  sltui  = 1'b0;
  xorri  = 1'b0;
  srli   = 1'b0;
  srai   = 1'b0;
  orri   = 1'b0;
  anddi  = 1'b0;

  // update
  case(opcode)
    7'b0110011: r_type          = 1'b1;
    7'b0010011: i_type          = 1'b1;
    7'b0000011: i_type          = 1'b1;
    7'b0100011: s_type          = 1'b1;
    7'b1100011: b_type          = 1'b0;
    7'b0110111: u_type          = 1'b1;
    7'b1101111: j_type          = 1'b1;
  endcase

  casez({opcode, funct3, funct7})
    // r-type
    {7'b0110011, 3'b000, 7'b0000000} : add   = 1'b1;
    {7'b0110011, 3'b000, 7'b0100000} : sub   = 1'b1;
    {7'b0110011, 3'b001, 7'b0000000} : sll   = 1'b1;
    {7'b0110011, 3'b010, 7'b0000000} : slt   = 1'b1;
    {7'b0110011, 3'b011, 7'b0000000} : sltu  = 1'b1;
    {7'b0110011, 3'b100, 7'b0000000} : xorr  = 1'b1;
    {7'b0110011, 3'b101, 7'b0000000} : srl   = 1'b1;
    {7'b0110011, 3'b101, 7'b0100000} : sra   = 1'b1;
    {7'b0110011, 3'b110, 7'b0000000} : orr   = 1'b1;
    {7'b0110011, 3'b111, 7'b0000000} : andd  = 1'b1;
    // i-type
    {7'b0010011, 3'b000, 7'b???????} : addi  = 1'b1;
    {7'b0010011, 3'b010, 7'b???????} : slti  = 1'b1;
    {7'b0010011, 3'b011, 7'b???????} : sltiu = 1'b1;
    {7'b0010011, 3'b100, 7'b???????} : xori  = 1'b1;
    {7'b0010011, 3'b110, 7'b???????} : ori   = 1'b1;
    {7'b0010011, 3'b111, 7'b???????} : andi  = 1'b1;
    {7'b0010011, 3'b001, 7'b???????} : slli  = 1'b1;
    {7'b0010011, 3'b101, 7'b???????} : srli  = 1'b1;
    {7'b0010011, 3'b101, 7'b???????} : srai  = 1'b1;
  endcase
end
```